# Plotting pulse width or frequency of a pulse train LTspice

Tags: ltspice

Maybe I'm demanding from the tool too much but I'm wondering whether the following possible in LTspice.

I have a PWL file(time and voltage values) which can be read and plotted by LTspice. This is a pulse train with 0 to 5V amplitude but with varying frequency.

To see how the frequency or the period changes for each successive pulse, is there a way to plot or extract the frequency or the period of each pulse?

Comment: Use an integrator and sample the voltage when the pulse falls. This of course relies on the mark-space ratio being constant.

Comment: LTspice has some triggers. Look up the .MEAS card in LTspice's help.